# Implement inversion list in VBA?

Tags: vba, data-structures

How can an [inversion list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_list) of (positive) integers be implemented in a flexible and efficient way in VBA? In particular, with which underlying data structure?

It will be used to represent a set of positive integers.

A function will be used to add the integers in the range from A to B to the set. The function will return the set of of integers from A to B that were not added because they were already in the set. In other words, the function will return the intersection of the old set (as it was before the function was called) and the set of integers in given range.

Another function will return whether the integer A is in the set (Boolean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a data structure, you would just use an array (of integers or doubles or whatever). In VBA it is easiest to just use a variant to pass an array to a function. If you want `O(1)` appending, you could use an `ArrayList` (not native VBA, but able to be used in VBA) Here is a search function for an array implementation:

```
Function InRanges(A As Variant, item As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim lower As Long, mid As Long, upper As Long
    lower = LBound(A)
    upper = UBound(A)

    If item < A(lower) Or item >= A(upper) Then
        InRanges = False
    Else 'A(lower) =< item < A(upper)
        Do Until upper = lower + 1
            mid = Int((lower + upper) / 2)
            If A(mid) = item Then
                'return result of a check if this occurs at an even or odd location
                InRanges = ((mid - LBound(A)) Mod 2 = 0)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf item < A(mid) Then
                upper = mid
            Else 'A(mid) < item
                lower = mid
            End If
        Loop
        InRanges = ((lower - LBound(A)) Mod 2 = 0)
    End If
End Function
```

For testing purposes, I used the example from the Wikipedia article you gave:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    A = Array(10, 15, 25, 38)
    For i = 9 To 39
        Debug.Print i & ": " & InRanges(A, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

```
9: False
10: True
11: True
12: True
13: True
14: True
15: False
16: False
17: False
18: False
19: False
20: False
21: False
22: False
23: False
24: False
25: True
26: True
27: True
28: True
29: True
30: True
31: True
32: True
33: True
34: True
35: True
36: True
37: True
38: False
39: False
```

Comment: Thanks, I now have an implementation that uses an array and ReDims it whenever the number of ranges is changed. A function can add a range of positive integers to the set and return the set of overlap between the previous set and the added range. A function returns whether a given integer is in the set. A function returns the complement of the set. A function returns a textual representation of the set, with optional parameters to pass the symbols to be used before, inside and after the ranges. A test suite does operations on a set and checks results between each. The code is too long to post.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work. `ReDim Preserve` can be expensive (it copies the preserved data into the new array) so if you are doing that a lot and you don't mind going outside pure VBA, then you might want to look into [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) See [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html) for how to use them from VBA. After I wrote my answer I noticed that array lists even have a binary search method, so you should be able to code the membership check fairly easily.